# git --rebase -i a feature branch

Tags: git, github, rebase

I'm working on an open source project where I've forked their repository on github.
And I have made a branch of main with some modifications, adding vscode .devcontainer.
I do not wish to PR this branch onto the project I've forked. But I use it as a development environment.

Working on a new feature that I wish to PR to the project. I made a new branch from my modified branch and added the new feature here.

The following should visualize the branches where C is a commit and M is a merge

```
main - C1 - C2 ------------ C5---------
               \             \
        branch1 - C3 - C4 --- M1 -
                                  \
                           branch2 ---- C6 - C7
```

What I want to end up with, and what I thought I would end up with when doing `git --rebase -i main` is the following

```
                      branch2 ---- C6 - C7 --
                             /
main - C1 - C2 ------------ C5 ---------
               \             \
        branch1 - C3 - C4 --- M1 ----
```

But the commits I was presented with was only C5, C6, C7, I did not seem to rebase C6,C7 onto C1, C2, C5. so I ended up with a branch containing C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7

I solved it by making a new branch from main and then cherry picking C6, C7 onto it. But I really thought rebase would have helped me.

When I merged C5 into branch1 should I have rebased instead so C3, C4 would be moved after C5? or instead of rebasing onto main, should I have rebased on to C2? and then skipped all commits on branch1

Suggestions, alternatives and comments is very much welcome.

Comment: This could be tricky because you are attempting to rebase over a merge commit.

Comment: To preserve merge commits during rebases there is a dedicated `--rebase-merges` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo need

```
git rebase --onto main branch1 branch2
```

From [`man git-rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> ```
>     o---o---o---o---o  master
>         \
>          o---o---o---o---o  next
>                           \
>                            o---o---o  topic
> ```
>
> We want to make topic forked from branch master; for example, because the functionality on which topic depends was merged into the more stable master branch. We want our tree to look like this:
>
> ```
>    o---o---o---o---o  master
>        |            \
>        |             o'--o'--o'  topic
>         \
>          o---o---o---o---o  next
> ```
>
> We can get this using the following command:
>
> ```
> git rebase --onto master next topic
> ```

Comment: This answer doesn't help much, and rebase onto may not even work, given that `M1` is a merge commit.

Comment: `rebase --onto` is specifically done for that, see the sole example given: _"for example, because the functionality on which topic depends was merged into the more stable master branch"_. (even though this is the opposite here)

Comment: You're missing the point: Rebasing over a merge commit usually requires redoing the merge.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The answer is spot on. `branch1 branch2`  will _not_ try to rebase `M1` as `M1` is part of the history of `branch1` (if I understand the chart correctly, in my reading with the misplaced pointers) so only `M1..C7` commits (IOW, `C6` and `C7`) will be rebased on top of `master`.

Comment: This actually seems to have worked, just did a quick test. Thank you very much, I'll experiment further with it <3

Comment: Rebase is **extremely** handy once you are able to understand how it works.